# find two strings in output with && in bash

Tags: bash, sed, xargs

I want to look for two strings if they exists in my output and then pipe to pass them as arguments in next command.

ex:

```
for X = 1 to 100
    cat logX.txt | grep -e string1 -e string2 | rm logX.txt
```

but i don't know how to achieve above.

i have to check this for 100 files and delete which ever has those two strings in it. if anyone strings exist then i don't want to delete file.

Comment: Instead of pseudocode, could you describe what you want this code to do in English? For instance, do you want to run `rm` only if *both* strings are found? Only if neither is found? We can't tell what code *should* do by reading it, only what it *does* do.

Comment: Also, you need to have a blank line above a section that's indented for it to be formatted as code. Both melpone and I have submitted edits making that fix -- please try not to roll it back.

Comment: BTW, how long are these files? Is it worth trying to build a single-pass solution? Note that `grep -e foo -e bar` searches for `foo` *or* `bar`, not `foo` *and* `bar`.

Comment: Re: "i have to [...] delete which ever has those two strings in it. if anyone strings exist then i don't want to delete file": These two sentences seem to disagree: one says that you *do* want to delete files with those strings, one says that you *don't*. Can you clarify?

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you're using a numeric counter, rather than just `for file in log*.txt; do`?

Comment: Changing a question *after you already received a valid, correct answer for the original formulation* is not welcome here (questions that change in this way are what you may see referred to as "chameleon questions"). If you have outstanding questions, factor out the parts of your problem that were already answered, and ask a new question only about the remaining uncertainty (without repeating the parts of the question that were successfully answered).

Comment: I ADJUSTED MY QUESTION. SORRY ITS complex that is why. now its good of what i want to achieve.

Comment: I wrote my question again and its clear now. Please suggest.

Comment: okay - am marking this as answered coz i tried the below on files and it works. but i will raise another for my actual ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `find`:

```
find . -name 'log*.txt' -exec grep -E 'string1' {} \; -exec grep -E 'string2' {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

This would find `logN.txt`, grep for string1, if match then grep for string2, and if a match remove the file.

As per the comment below, add `-maxdepth 1` if you only want to find files the current directory.

Comment: (Also, it's recursing, into subdirectories, which wasn't requested; perhaps you want `-maxdepth 1`?)

Comment: *nod*. Works per spec as-edited, just inefficient with large files.

Comment: Good suggestion on the max depth.

Comment: BTW, you could make the last one `-exec rm -f -- {} +` so you don't call `rm` more times than necessary. (`-delete` is even more efficient since it directly invokes `unlink()`, but as a GNUism, may not be available on a POSIX-baseline `find`).

Comment: True enough. My `awk` foo is not so great as yours, hence the humble find.

Comment: Oh, btw -- I'd also suggest adding the `-q` argument to `grep`; that way it suppresses output from being printed, and (more importantly) stops reading a file after the first match is found rather than needing to scan all the way through even when the exit status is known.

Comment: i want to use the strings as variables. like this below

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete only files with both matches, `awk` -- being a full-fledged programming language which can be given an expression that checks for the flags independently -- is more appropriate than `grep` (which modifies its exit status based on whether *any* matches are found, not whether *all* expressions given are matched).

```
string1="first regex"
string2="second regex"
for ((x=1; x<=100; x++)); do
  file="log$x.txt"
  awk -v string1="$string1" -v string2="$string2" '
    BEGIN { found1=0; found2=0; }
    $0 ~ string1 { found1=1; }
    $0 ~ string2 { found2=1; }
    END { exit(!(found1 && found2)) }
  ' "$file" && rm -f -- "$file"
done
```

The `grep` equivalent would be much less efficient, since it has to read each file twice:

```
# MUCH SLOWER ON BIG FILES: Reads each file twice (up to the point where a match exists)
string1="first regex"
string2="second regex"
for ((x=1; x<=100; x++)); do
  file="log$x.txt"
  grep -q -e "$string1" -- "$file" && grep -q -e "$string2" -- "$file" && rm -f -- "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel:

```
parallel 'grep string1 log{}.txt && grep string2 log{}.txt && rm log{}.txt' ::: {1..100}
```

If you want to look at all log*.txt files, then this is shorter:

```
parallel 'grep string1 {} && grep string2 {} && rm {}' ::: log*.txt
```